# Setting Google Cloud Platform Log sink to a specific folder within a bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I have created five separate log export sinks within Google Cloud Stackdriver.  Currently they are all set to the same bucket (my-bucket) with the destination:

`storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket`

The bucket (my-bucket) has the following 5 folders:
iam, compute, firewall, project and storage

I would like to associate each log sink to one of those folders within my bucket, is this possible?  The answer from a related question ([Pointing multiple projects' log sinks to one bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291905/pointing-multiple-projects-log-sinks-to-one-bucket/47293197#47293197?newreg=de0bdde5bc2242e5a48a1d07fcffc0c2)) seems to indicate that it is, however, I do not understand the "FOLDER_ID" and if this is what I need and if so where do I get that.

I have tried to update the destination manually in google cloud shell with the command

`gcloud logging sinks update my-compute-log-sink storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/compute`

and get confirmation that the sink has been updated, however, running `gcloud logging sinks list` shows no change and now I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently possible.

The location you used when attempting to update the sink (when you include the directory) will only point to the bucket as a whole despite adding the additional information after it, so when you see the updated message, you are probably overwriting the current sink with the same information as before.

I've opened a feature request to see if it will be possible to implement the usage of specified bucket directory locations in Google Cloud Platform logging sinks. You can follow it here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/72036905

There is also  a separate feature request which relates to the task you are trying to acehive that you can follow here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/69371200

In terms of the FOLDER_ID value, that's not related to the folder in the bucket, but relates to the  Cloud Platform Resource Hierarchy as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-folders). It's therefore not something related to your main issue.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: No problem! If this information helped you please upvote the answer. Also,  If it the information answered your question, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The logging sink destination (for cloud storage) must be a bucket.

The folder referred to in the answer to [Pointing multiple projects' log sinks to one bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47293197/395927) is for grouping projects. That answer links to the documentation for [folders](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-folders), which describes them as:

> Folders are nodes in the Cloud Platform Resource Hierarchy. A folder
>   can contain projects, other folders, or a combination of both.

Cloud Storage does not support something like 'folders' within buckets, only buckets and objects. See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms